# CMS Pages are not reflecting changes even after upgrade-deploy-flush-clean

Tags: magento2, cms-pages

The problem is that the CMS pages are created once they are newly added.
But when i edit and do changes from backend(admin) the changes are not showing even after upgrade and deploy which is followed by flushing.
when i am using mgt-development tool 
the toolbar show the mode of application.when i created a CMS page in default mode and i change the mode after it, it still shows default mode for it and other dynamic pages show correct mode

Comment: Does your changes are reflected into the preview section of CMS page?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya We migrated recently to M2 and this is happening with every CMS pages.No CMS are upgrading on frontend. The changes are taking place in Database but not on frontend

Comment: Which magento mode do you have?

Comment: Currently its in developer mode